# Filter table of entries and exclude any that are found in another table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table of staff data which I am filtering based on their employment status not being terminated and if they're a development role. To do this I have the following function :

`=FILTER(FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,(StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Status]<>"Employment Terminated")*(StaffDetailsTbl[Dev Role]="Yes"))),{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0})`

I have another table called AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl which has a matching Employee column and I'd like to check if the employee in the StaffDetailsTbl exists in AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl and if they do exclude them. I have first started to try and find if there is a match and include them only, with the view I can then flip this logic somehow to exclude the matches

`=FILTER(FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,(StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Status]<>"Employment Terminated")*(StaffDetailsTbl[Dev Role]="Yes")*(MATCH(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee]))),{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0})`

Unfortunately this is giving me an error with the match. Does anyone have any advice on how I can approach this please?

Comment: Wrap your `MATCH` statement within `ISNUMBER`.

Comment: Hi @Jos Woolley, that unfortunately gives a calc error `=FILTER(FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,(StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Status]<>"Employment Terminated")*(StaffDetailsTbl[Dev Role]="Yes")*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee])))),{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0})`

Comment: Figured out a solution - 

`=FILTER(FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,(StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Status]<>"Employment Terminated")*(StaffDetailsTbl[Dev Role]="Yes")*(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee], AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl, 1, FALSE)),1,0 ))),{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0})`

Comment: What is `ISNUMBER(MATCH(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee]))))`? Why is `AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl` in there? It should be `ISNUMBER(MATCH(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee],0))`

Comment: oops. Thanks for the spot Jos. I did find a different solution and posted the answer. Your fix sorted the error in my original though and found every match. I flipped using the following to give the same result as my answer and will post it as an alternative suggestion: `NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee],0))) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved it:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,(StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Status]<>"Employment Terminated")*(StaffDetailsTbl[Dev Role]="Yes")*(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee], AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl, 1, FALSE)),1,0 ))),{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0})
```

By multiplying the filter by `IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee], AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl, 1, FALSE)),1,0 )` it filters only those entries from the StaffDetailsTbl Table that do not exist in the AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl Table.

An alternative solution from Jos Woolley using `NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee],0)))` also works, giving a final solution of:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(StaffDetailsTbl,(StaffDetailsTbl[Employment Status]<>"Employment Terminated")*(StaffDetailsTbl[Dev Role]="Yes")*( NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee],0))))),{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0})
```

Comment: Since you're using Office 365 `IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP()))` can be changed into `XLOOKUP` which has it's own `IF ISERROR` built in.

Comment: Hi P.b I tried switching it out for `XLOOKUP(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee], AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],1)` but unfortunately I'm getting an error, any idea how I've gone wrong?

Comment: Excel has prebuild formula helpers on screen, it says which condition to put where: `=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array,return_array,[if_not_found],[match_mode],[search_mode])`